# Discuss the convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n(-1)^n(z-i)^n}{4^n(n^2+1)^{5/2}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Discuss the convergence of the series
> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n(-1)^n(z-i)^n}{4^n(n^2+1)^{5/2}}$

So by the ration test, I know that the series converges when $|z-i|<1$ and diverges when $|z-i|>1$. However, I don't know what happen if $|z-i|=1$ since the only way i know is to check $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} |c_n|$ but in this case, the limit is $0$ so I cannot conclude anything about the convergence. So is there any thing I can do?

Comment: Use Comparison Test.

Comment: I see. Thank you

Comment: Actually, the radius of convergence is $4$, not $1$.

Comment: Right, because I was doing another quiz so got them mess up. Thank

Comment: $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\,\dfrac{n\, x^n}{(n^2+1)^{5/2}}$ should be vey close to a straight line.

Comment: Try Raabe's test at a point on the radius of convergence.